# C# convert datetime to custom format

Tags: c#, sql

I'm querying a `datetime` (dd/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss) value from a database and inserting it in a list like this:

```
ord.invoiceDate = dt.Rows[i]["invoicedate"].ToString();
```

How can I convert this string to a custom format like `dd-MM-YYYY` ? I don't want the hours minutes and seconds.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx. I think you are looking for ord.invoiceDate = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["invoicedate"].ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

Comment: What is the datatype of `ord.invoiceDate` ?

Comment: @Habib it's a string ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
ord.invoiceDate = ((DateTime)dt.Rows[i]["invoicedate"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the Format of date time string, then you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` method as below to convert it to DateTime. If you not sure about the format then use `DateTime.TryParseExact` it will not raise exception on fail to convert but you will get null value as result.

```
var invoiceDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dt.Rows[i]["invoicedate"],
              "dd/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

After you got the result you can convert to string by giving format as below

```
ord.invoiceDate = invoiceDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```